# Mod_Rewrite category directory

Tags: mod-rewrite

I would like to forward categories to index.php from root directory; Here is the example;

domain.com/en/category1/category2/ ---> index.php?lang=en&cat1=category1&cat2=category2

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*  /index.php?lang=$1&cat1=$2&cat2=$3 [QSA,NC]
```

Comment: It should work. Where do you put the rewrite rule? If inside <Directory> or in a .htaccess you should remove the leading /